# Expect get specify information from output

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I'm trying to build a script that gather information of our Cisco devices. I'm using bash and calling Expect in order to send command to the devices. I'm able to send command and get the output via the log function. 
What I'd like to do is get the output of the line "Serial number: SERIAL_NUMBER"

Here is what I have so far:

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
set timeout 5
spawn ssh $Username@$IP ena\r$Password\rshow version \rexit\r
expect "password"
send "$Password\r"
expect -re {^[Serial Number: ].+}
puts "S/N: $expect_out(4,string)"
expect "*#"
expect eof
EOF
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
S/N: (4,string)
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
```

I tried using other spawn_ID and still get the same error. I'm not 100% sure how tcl works so if someone could help me out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is this:

```
expect -re {^[Serial Number: ].+}
puts "S/N: $expect_out(4,string)"
```

and that it should be:

```
expect -re {^[Serial Number: ](.+)}
puts "S/N: $expect_out(1,string)"
```

I've put a “capture group” in the regular expression, and I pick out that group for printing with `expect_out(1,string)` because it is the *first* such capture group; they're numbered from one (because zero is the entire matched string, which you usually don't need when working with expect).

---

Of course, that assumes that the code is working at all. If the other end of the connection has decided to tell you to go away, the expect script will fail. You should turn on the debugging mode for expect and see exactly what is going on. You should **definitely** check out the answer to this question for ways to debug that.

[Expect Scripting Logging not finishing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645174/301832)

Comment: The regular expression is fine. I've tested it with a online REGEX simulator.